# Cannot call a nested function

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the question says, I can't call a nested function!
Here's the JavaScript:

```
var n;
var i = 0;

$("#men").click(function(){
    $("#reshead").slideToggle("300");
});

$("#nxt").click(function() {
    pic(i+=n);
});

$(window).on("scroll", function() {

  if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $("#header").addClass("scroll");
  } else {
    $("#header").removeClass("scroll");
  }
});

function pic(n) {
    if(n=1){
        dx1();
    } else if (n==2) {
        dx2();
    } else if (n=3){
        dx3();
    } else{
        n=0;
    }   
}

function dx1() {
    document.getElementById("picb").style.backgroundImage='url("src/black-belt.png")';
}

function dx2() {
    document.getElementById("picb").style.cssText+='background-image:url(src/kut.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;    width:auto;height:auto;';
}

function dx3() {
    document.getElementById("picb").style.cssText+='background-image:url(src/slmb.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;    width:auto;height:auto;';
}
```

I tried everything possible. Nothing happens. The code is for a slideshow in which the background image alone changes. 
I first tried it in jQuery but it didn't happen. So I tried in plain JavaScript and it still doesn't work.

Comment: This is a case of using CSS classes and not appending the same thing over and over to the style...

Comment: Using a tool like jslint or jshint would have pointed you to the error.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(n=1)
```

and

```
else if(n=3)
```

are assingments and not comparison operators...

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a value to `n` so it's always entering to the first `if`. Try using `==` operator:

```
function pic(n) {
    if(n==1){
        dx1();
    }
    else if(n==2){
        dx2();
    }
    else if(n==3){
        dx3();
    }
    else{
        n=0;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that even with the syntax fixes, you will still run into a problem trying to add `undefined` to `0`.

```
pic(i+=n);
```

where the first time it is called `i` equals `0` and `n` equals `undefined`. Afterwards, `i` will equal `NaN` and `n` will equal `0`.